# 100ANDRO folder visible over USB but not on the phone

Tags: usb

I've migrated a Sony device to a Pixel 4a. I've got an 100ANDRO folder inside DCIM. This folder is visible over USB connection. I cannot delete this folder (or the files inside) because "The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected" (which is not the case). I cannot see the 100ANDRO folder from my phone itself. How do I get rid of that folder?

Comment: Solved myself: created 100ANDRO folder on the phone and that made the old one to disappear. 20GB+ sorage recovered!

Comment: Most likely the Android Media Database had not yet processed the files in this folder. A device reboot or just waiting should had also "recovered" this folder.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!